# Can I alias a type inside of a trait's definition, without the compiler assuming that I am defining an associated type with a default?

Tags: rust, traits, type-alias, associated-types

The code below doesn't compile on stable Rust 1.52:

```rust
trait Trait {
    type Foo;
}

trait OtherTrait {
    type Bar: Trait;
    type MyFoo = <Self::Bar as Trait>::Foo; // This is currently illegal...
    
    // ...but I want to be able to write this:
    fn example1() -> Self::MyFoo;

    /// Instead of having to write this:
    fn example2() -> <Self::Bar as Trait>::Foo;
}
```

The compiler complains that "associated type defaults are unstable". However, I don't want `MyFoo` to be an associated type with a default, only a convenient alias for `<Self::Bar as Trait>::Foo` inside the body of `OtherTrait`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve this?

Not exactly that, but you can achieve similar result by defining an ordinary type alias outside the trait:

```
type OtherFoo<T> = <<T as OtherTrait>::Bar as Trait>::Foo;

trait OtherTrait {
    type Bar: Trait;
    fn example1() -> OtherFoo<Self>;
}
```

Where you intended to write `Bla::MyFoo`, or the longer `<T as OtherTrait>::MyFoo` for a generic `T`, you can write `OtherFoo<Bla>` and `OtherFoo<T>` respectively. It works nicely if you can get over it not being scoped inside `OtherTrait`.